# Is it possible to pass an arraylist object to sql procedure with sql server 2000 and java 1.4?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, insertion

I have defined a class FieldProperty with some of properties corresponding to field defined in it.ArrayList object contains objects of class FieldProperty. now i want to store data in table .There is one record in table corresponding to each object of FieldProperty.if i call query for each record insertion.It will be very slow.Is there any way to pass object of arraylist to stored procedure and then i can retrieve data in stored procedure ?If this is not possible,What is best solution for  this problem?

Platform Info
Sql server 2000
java 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. Either send as CSV/XML etc amd parse into a table
   [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2000.html)
2. Use parameters, one per field (makes sense if fixed number of attributes per type)
3. Staging table/bulk upload, copy to final table as part of stored proc call afterwards